# Use sed to print from the very first line until the line containing the last occurrence of a pattern?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I know the following commands will print up to the first occurrence of a certain pattern but will not include the later occurrences:

```
sed -n '1,/<pattern>/p' <file>

sed '/<pattern>/q' <file>
```

For example lets say I have a file having the following lines:

```
this is a cow   
this is a goat  
this is a some fish  
this is a fishie  
this is a fish  
this is a lion  
this is a cat
```

Now the outputs:

```
$ sed '/fish/q' file  

this is a cow  
this is a goat  
this is a some fish 

$ sed -n '1,/fish/p' file  

this is a cow  
this is a goat  
this is a some fish
```

I want the output starting from the very first line till the line containing the last occurrence of **fish** i.e. my desired output is:

```
this is a cow   
this is a goat  
this is a some fish  
this is a fishie  
this is a fish
```

How to do that using `sed`?

Comment: `sed -n '/fish/p'` ?

Comment: Right you are..

Comment: I have updated the question properly and hope it will be removed from hold.

Comment: @KasiyA: Yes, Its working properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ tac infile | sed -n '/fish/,$p' |tac
```

In general case if you run below sed command, you will get all line from first matched pattern to end of input file.

```
$ sed -n '/fish/,$p' file

this is a some fish
this is a fishie
this is a fish
this is a lion
this is a cat
```

So my solution is: If we run `tac` command on input file your last matched pattern will change to as first pattern. see the result of `tac infile`:

```
$ tac infile

this is a cat
this is a lion
this is a fish
this is a fishie
this is a some fish
this is a goat
this is a cow
```

The `tac` command is the same as `cat` command, while `tac` prints files in reverse order.

Now if we run our first sed command, you will get all lines first matched pattern to end of input file. like:

```
$ tac infile | sed -n '/fish/,$p'
this is a fish
this is a fishie
this is a some fish
this is a goat
this is a cow
```

Ok, finished. We only need to run `tac` command again to reverse back the lines to original order:

```
$ tac infile | sed -n '/fish/,$p' |tac
this is a cow
this is a goat
this is a some fish
this is a fishie
this is a fish
```

Done!

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly simple - it just takes a little coordination between `sed`'s two buffers. For example:

```
sed -n 'H;/fish/!d;$!n;x;p;G
' <<\INFILE
this is a cow
this is a goat
this is a some fish
this is a fishie
this is a fish
this is a lion
this is a cat
INFILE
```

That command appends every line to `H`old space following an inserted `\n`ewline character. Any line which does `!`not match `/fish/` is immediately thereafter `d`eleted from output. Which leaves us with only `/fish/` lines. So the line is overwritten with the `n`ext line of input. Then pattern and `h`old spaces are swapped - we did just `H`old the line after all. Now pattern space is `H`old space and vice-versa. So we just `p`rint whatever was saved from the last time a `/fish/` line matched.

This can only get up to the last occurrence of a match because it only `p`rints when it finds a match - and it stores intervening lines in the interim. Still, it only stores as little as necessary between matches - each time the buffers are e`x`changed they are refreshed. Here's your output:

```
this is a cow   
this is a goat  
this is a some fish  
this is a fishie  
this is a fish
```

Thanks very much to don cristi for showing me that I sometimes skipped a fish. It now makes certain to push the buffer to both ends each time it is refreshed - and each turn to overwrite the current pattern space before deleting it - in case. It will work with a fish on the first line or the last, and any line in between as near as I can tell.

Another thing I was doing was pulling the `n`ext line on the last line - which is a big `sed` no-no. Thanks again to don for helping me with that as well.

A more thorough example:

```
sed 'x;/./G;//!x;/fish/p;//s/.*//;x;d'
```

That handles a few problems surrounding the other better, I hope. Pattern/`h`old spaces are e`x`changed every cycle - and this is to avoid getting extra blank lines as a result of the edit `s///`ubstitution at the end of the command. So the buffers are swapped and if the hold buffer is not empty the the current line is appended into that buffer following a `\n`ewline character - which is where the extra lines would come from otherwise. Else the buffers are just swapped back and `h`old space remains empty for the current cycle. As near as I can tell, this command preserves all blank lines and everything else - but merely stops printing at the last match.

Some of the difficulty I had with this is commonly associated with `h`old space - the only way to use it effectively is to fall short of - fall behind - the line cycle in order to compare old lines with older. My usual preference is for an `N;P;D` loop. You might do this thing using something along those lines like...

```
sed -ne :n -e '/fish/!N;//p;//!bn'
```

There `sed` continuously appends the `N`ext line of input to pattern space and `b`ranches back to the `:n` label to try again if *fish* does not match any of the lines it has built-up thus far. It only `p`rints lines - or line-sequences - which match `fish` before dumping the contents at line-cycle end and starting anew with a fresh buffer.

I purposely do not test for the last line here - if the last line matches it will be printed, else - and with `-n` this holds true even for GNU `sed` - the loop will just end the file all of its own last line or no.

Comment: @don_crissti - correct! It's not about blank lines though - it's more about adjacent fishes. They get swallowed when they're near one another - specifically when `n` doesn't get checked and another fish happens in the meanwhile. I doubly populate the buffer - it will still refresh w/ every exchange and so on, but once per turn the buffer is held *and* got so nothing slips by. I'm about to post the edit. Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: @don_crissti - please try it again if you will. I threw the stuff you mentioned at it.

Comment: @don_crissti - I could do that, but I don't I have that problem - I think... I'll check again. I can explicitly check the last line, of course. In any case, I do very much appreciate your help. Back in a few, I hope.

Comment: @don_crissti - I saw what you meant and figured out why, I think. If you find the time, try it again? I appreciate it.

Comment: @don_crissti - ok. fixed. I hope. I admit - you have shaken my confidence, but I was pretty busy earlier. Anyway, thanks for the test data - I verified it works at least with the file you linked me.

Comment: Yes, now it works with all sorts of input. Nice !

Comment: @don_crissti - the problem all along was `n` - it is convenient in that it overwrites pattern space with the `n`ext input line and so clears the buffer instantly - but then i never tested that line for *fish*. i could have set a branch condition and jumped back - but i got frustrated and kept it at the start of the script. anyway, it is still very fast - and i prefer to work future input into a constant algorithm rather than stopping every once in awhile to compare old lines - that is what i did with the `N` loop. do hope i figure out the `n` thing though - i have in similar scripts before...

Comment: @mikeserv your first command doesn't work well. see test input [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9395126/). also your explanation for commands isn't match with your commands which you used.

Comment: @KaisyA - im aware. thats what the others are for, but i should edit it out probably. the problem stems from two points of input - the comments elsewhere here get into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use awk which might be shorter than Sed:

```
awk ' /^fish/ { print $0 }' filename.txt
```

Some people may write this:

```
awk ' /^fish/ { print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 }' filename.txt
```

The `$n` represents a column.  The shortcut `$0` represents the entire line.

Comment: Please check my desired output as your answer will print the lines containing "fish" at first but i want the output to be from the first line till the line containing the last occurrence of **fish**.

Comment: Fix your question stating that in words as the question is on hold.

Comment: I have updated the question too..

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but after some edit iterations I believe you should rather use `pcregrep` for this task. For example if the input is

```
this is a cow
this is a goat
this is a some fish
this is a fishie
this is a fish
this is a lion
this is a cat
this is a fisherman
this is a dog
```

and desire output

```
this is a cow
this is a goat
this is a some fish
this is a fishie
this is a fish
```

then

```
pcregrep -M '(.|\n)*fish.*(?=(.|\n)*fish.*)'
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '$/.put if m/^ .* fish/ for lines.join("\n");'
```

Sample Input:

```
this is a cow   
this is a goat  
this is a some fish  
this is a fishie  
this is a fish  
this is a lion  
this is a cat
```

Sample Output:

```
this is a cow   
this is a goat  
this is a some fish  
this is a fishie  
this is a fish
```

Note, the regex above will terminate on the word `fish` which works fine as long as `fish` is the last word on the line. If, however, the OP wants to capture the entire *last line* (so that for example the entire word `fisherman` is returned), then change the regex matcher above to `m/^ .* fish .*? $$ /` .

https://raku.org