# Deleting all lines after first occurrence of a string in a line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a large file `test.txt` like this example:

```
foo
before ...
before some line 
foo something interesting bar
after some lines
after ...
bar
```

How do I create a new file with just the lines before the first occurrence of the string "`something interesting`" with basic bash commands like `sed` or `grep` (not `awk`, I need this on an embedded device without awk)?

Comment: A slight nitpick (and clarification). `sed` and `grep` are not `bash` commands; they are separate commands, which can be invoked from any shell you happen to be using.

Comment: [Show all the file up to the match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11305)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed '/something interesting/,$d' < file > newfile
```

Which can be optimized to:

```
sed -n '/something interesting/q;p' < file > newfile
```

for `sed` to quit as soon as it finds the pattern.

Which with the GNU implementation of `sed`, as noted by @RakeshSharma, can be simplified to

```
sed '/something interesting/Q' < file > newfile
```

To truncate the file in-place, with `ksh93` instead of `bash`, you could do:

```
printf '' <>; file >#'*something interesting*'
```

- `<>;` is like the standard `<>` redirection operator (open in read+write) except that the file is truncated at the end if the command is successful.
- `<#pattern` seeks to the start of the next line matching the pattern.

(note that it seems to work (with ksh93u+ at least) with `printf ''` on stdout but not with some other builtin commands like `true`, `:` or `eval`. Looks like [a bug](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/61). Also it can't be the last command of a script ([another bug](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/9))).

Comment: @RakeshSharma, good point. I've added it

Comment: The first suggestion works perfectly, thanks. I spent some time to realize how to use it wit shell variable expansion: `sed "/${VAR}/,$ d"` - note the white space between `$` and `d`.

Comment: And the GNU sed command to edit in place would simply be `sed -i '/something interesting/Q' 'file'`